# How web scrape with request, Bs4 when there is a script result?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I am trying to get some data from this website:

http://www.espn.com.br/futebol/resultados/_/liga/BRA.1/data/20181018

When I inspect the page on my browser I can see all the values I need on the HTML. I want to fetch the game result and the players names (for each date, in this example 2018-10-18)

On no game days the website shows:

"Sem jogos nesta data", which is it easy to find on browser inspection:
[image: example]

But when using

```
url = 'http://www.espn.com.br/futebol/resultados/_/liga/todos/data/20181018'
page = requests.get(url, "lxml")
```

The output is basically the website  where I can't find the phrase "Sem jogos nesta data"

How can I get fetch the HTML containing the script results? Is it possible with request? urllib?

Comment: As [alican](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52939261/4632627) has said, that text/div is not present in the page source. It's loaded by JavaScript after the page loads and injected into the DOM. If you "View Source" instead of "Inspect" you'll see the original document, before any JavaScript has been executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the data you are looking for that comes from their backend API. I would use `selenium-python` package instead of `requests`.

Here is example:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.espn.com.br/futebol/resultados/_/liga/todos/data/20181018")
value = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="events"]/div')
drive.close()
```

I didn't check the code but it should be working